# Что стоит добавить в подсказку командной строки?

Tags: shell, prompt

Стандартная строка приглашения выглядит достаточно аскетично: имя пользователя, имя машины, разделитель. Что еще реально полезно добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Рабочую директорию, например. Кусок из моего ~/.bashrc (почти стандартный, измененная расцветка):

```
PS1='\[\e[1;33m\]\u\[\e[1;32m\]@\\[\e[1;36m\]\h\[\e[1;32m\]:\\[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```